# Cannot install scipy with pypy (g++ build error)

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, pypy

As of 2020, installing scipy with pypy is possible. ([Is it possible to install scipy under pypy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34729783/is-it-possible-to-install-scipy-under-pypy/50201186#50201186))

```
pypy3 -mpip install scipy
```

However, the wheel fails with this kind of error:

```
  error: Command "g++ -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC -I/tmp/pip-build-env-lfdsn__t/overlay/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/lib/pypy3/include -c scipy/_lib/_uarray/_uarray_dispatch.cxx -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/scipy/_lib/_uarray/_uarray_dispatch.o -MMD -MF build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/scipy/_lib/_uarray/_uarray_dispatch.o.d -std=c++14 -fvisibility=hidden" failed with exit status 1


  ERROR: Failed building wheel for scipy
```

Failed to build scipy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for scipy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Using --no-use-pep517 option give similar result:

```
    error: Command "g++ -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC -I/home/ezako/.local/lib/pypy3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/lib/pypy3/include -c scipy/_lib/_uarray/_uarray_dispatch.cxx -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/scipy/_lib/_uarray/_uarray_dispatch.o -MMD -MF build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/scipy/_lib/_uarray/_uarray_dispatch.o.d -std=c++14 -fvisibility=hidden" failed with exit status 1 
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/pypy3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-2ffzze2v/scipy/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-2ffzze2v/scipy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-8avik0f1/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/ezako/.local/include/python3.6/scipy Check the logs for full command output.
```

Numpy has been sucessfully installed with pypy3.

```
➜ pypy3 -V
Python 3.6.9 (7.3.0+dfsg-1~ppa1~ubuntu19.04, Dec 26 2019, 11:14:16)
[PyPy 7.3.0 with GCC 8.3.0]
```

Comment: What does `pypy -V` show? You should be using at least PyPy 7.3.0

Comment: ... and why `g++` and not `gcc` ?

Comment: answer edited with this information.

Comment: Can you try with `pypy3 -mpip install -v scipy` and report what actually is failing? It seems to be some compilation, but exactly what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what worked for me. I unpacked the [latest nightly](http://buildbot.pypy.org/nightly/py3.6/)

```
pypy -mensurepip
pypy -mpip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
pypy -mpip install numpy pybind11
pypy -mpip install scipy
```

Apparently you need to install pybind11 separately since it does not work properly in a PEP 517 isolated build.

Comment: It works ! I also installed pybind11 before scipy in my previous test. My guess is the nightly build fixed the bug I encountered.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem but none of the solutions that I found helped me.
I tried:

- Upgrading pip
- Downgrading pip
- Use `--no-cache-dir` flag
- Upgrading `setuptools` and `wheel`
- Use `--default-pip` flag
- Use `--no-use-pep517` flag

So I try to install it manually with [official manual](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/building/linux.html) and everything works fine.

```
git clone https://github.com/scipy/scipy.git
cd scipy
git submodule update --init
pypy -mpip install .
```

You may need to set `BLAS`, `LAPACK` and `ATLAS` libraries paths.